# Parsing text file with specific start and end indicator for python3

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I would like to seek your help to resolve my issue on Python script for parsing textfile below:

```
Server01-XXX-YYY-ZZZ  

-------------CPU01 --------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------
Wed Jul 04, 23:30 
--------------------------------------------------
MEASUREMENT: 'TEDT'

Number       Value  measName
     1         131  MEMORYTOT
     2         131  MEMORY01
--------------------------------------------------
Wed Jul 04, 23:45 
--------------------------------------------------
MEASUREMENT: 'TEDT'

Number       Value  measName
     1         150  MEMORYTOT
     2         150  MEMORY01

-------------END OF CPU01 ----------------------


-------------TOTAL ----------------------------<< The script will start to parse when find this 'TOTAL' line

--------------------------------------------------
Wed Jul 04, 23:30 
--------------------------------------------------
MEASUREMENT: 'TEDT'

Number       Value  measName
     1         100  MEMORYTOT
     2         120  MEMORY01
--------------------------------------------------
Wed Jul 04, 23:45 
--------------------------------------------------
MEASUREMENT: 'TEDT'

Number       Value  measName
     1         500  MEMORYTOT
     2         520  MEMORY01

-------------END OF TOTAL --------------------<< The script will end to parse when find this 'END OF TOTAL' line
```

The expected result as below (txt file):

```
Name    Server       Time     MEMORYTOT    MEMORY01
-------------------------------------------------
TED    Server01     23:30        100         120
TED    Server01     23:45        500         520
```

This is my python code. I have tried to adapt from this link https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ as the pattern of the textfile is almost the same but still stuck to implement on my case.

Really appreciated your help or suggestion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

regex_dict = {
    'node_name'       : re.compile(r'(?P<nodeName>\w+)-.*'),     
    'starter_regex'   : re.compile(r'(?P<TOTAL>TOTAL)'),
    'date_time_regex' : re.compile(r'((?P<dateTimeRegex>\w{3}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{2}\,\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}))'),
    'MEASUREMENT'     : re.compile(r'(?P<MEASUREMENT>\w+\:\s+(\'\w+\'))'),
    'counters'        : re.compile(r'(Number +Value +(?P<counterName>Name))'),
    'counter_value'   : re.compile(r'\s+\d{1,}\s+(?P<value>\d{1,})\s+(?P<name>\w+)'),
}

def _parse_line(line):
    for key, value in regex_dict.items():
        match = value.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None

def parse_file(filepath):
   
    list = []
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        # Read line by line and process 
        line = file_object.readline() 
        while line:
            key, match = _parse_line(line)
           
            if key == 'node_name':
                node_name = match.group('nodeName')
            if key == 'starter_regex':
                starter_line = match.group('TOTAL')
           
            if key == 'date_time_regex':
                date_time = match.group('dateTimeRegex')
           
            if key == 'MEASUREMENT':
                measurement = match.group('MEASUREMENT')
           
            if key == 'counters':
                counters = match.group('counterName')
                line = file_object.readline()
                while line:
                    key, match = _parse_line(line)
           
                    if key == 'node_name':
                        counter_value = match.group('value')
                        counter_name = match.group('name')
                        
                        dict = {
                            'MEASUREMENT'  : measurement,
                            'node_name'    : node_name,
                            'date_time'    : date_time,
                            'counter_name' : counter_name,
                            'counter_value': counter_value,
                        }
                        
                        list.append(dict)
                    line = file_object.readline()

            line = file_object.readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'inputfile.log'
    parse_file(filepath)
```

Comment: "but doesn't work" - what does it mean? How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: I reworded 'but doesn't work'. Actually I am still stuck to produce my expected result when using a dictionary before putting it into List.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script to print the table you want (maybe some debugging will be needed):

```
import re


with open('inputfile.log', 'r') as f_in:
    txt = f_in.read()

server_name = txt.splitlines()[0].split('-')[0]

rows, columns = [], []
for total in re.findall(r'^-+TOTAL[^\n]+(.*?)^-+END OF TOTAL', txt, flags=re.S|re.M):
    for time, name, cnt, column in re.findall(r'(\d+:\d+)|MEASUREMENT: \'([A-Z\d]+)\'|(?:\d+\s+(\d+)\s+([A-Z\d]+))', total):
        if time:
            rows.append({'Time': time, 'Server': server_name})
        elif name:
            rows[-1]['Name'] = name
        else:
            if column not in columns:
                columns.append(column)
            rows[-1][column] = cnt

f = '{:<15}' * (3+len(columns))
print(f.format('Name', 'Server', 'Time', *columns))
print('-' * (15*(3+len(columns))))
for d in rows:
    print(f.format(d['Name'], d['Server'], d['Time'], *[d.get(c, '-') for c in columns]))
```

Prints:

```
Name           Server         Time           MEMORYTOT      MEMORY01       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEDT           Server01       23:30          100            120            
TEDT           Server01       23:45          500            520
```